# OpsHub - Migrating TFS to VSO returns OpsHub-012300 Access Denied reading changeset

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm attempting to perform a TFS to VSO migration using OpsHub and getting the error below.

Error in execution of Job : tfsserver\tpc to myvsoaccount.visualstudio.com| tfsserver\tpc to myvsoaccount.visualstudio.com| TFS Source 1400116587686 Source TFS 1400116587688 'Demo' Commit Information  tfsserver\tpc to myvsoaccount.visualstudio.com| TFS Source 1400116587686 Source TFS 1400116587688 TFS Commit Information

OpsHub-012300: Error occurred in generating events. Caused by Error in getting All Change Events : OH-TFS-Connector-0030: Error occurred in executing operation getTotalRevisions. Server Error : TF14098: Access Denied: User 'demouser' needs Read permission(s) for at least one item in changeset 303462.

The particular changeset was the last changeset checked in. I have access to see that changeset and is contents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS to VisualStudio Online Migration - Access to directory is denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689522/tfs-to-visualstudio-online-migration-access-to-directory-is-denied)

Comment: I have also some trouble to understand why I was getting this error. It could be because of a specific file wich have differents rights than his parent because it doesn't Inherit permission. You could check this link, it help me to solve this (first) OpsHib issue : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/congyiw/2011/10/20/tfs-version-control-permissions-why-cant-i-branchrenamedelete-x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes due to the user (configured on the TFS side) not having read access to all the changesets in the collection. Read access to all the changesets is needed for processing/recovery purposes.

It is recommended that the user configured have admin privileges so that they can read all the changesets.

Comment: Thank you. I applied admin privileges to the user and the migration was successful.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this error by granting Read permissions to the TFS2010 Project Collection. Full admin privileges were not necessary. Even if you are the Project Administrator on the project itself you still need Read for the entire Collection.

(I would make this a comment, but don't have enough rep)

Comment: No, that should be an answer not a comment.