# TFS to VisualStudio Online Migration - Access to directory is denied

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm trying the new **OpsHub TFS** to Visual Studio Online migration tool and have run into a snag.  After successfully setting up the migration configuration, I begin the migration.
On the first changeset of the migration, I receive the error:
 `"OH_SCM_009: Error occurred while sync. Access to the path 'O:\w15_2\ProjectName'"`
Where `ProjectName` is the name of my project.

Through deletion and recreation of the project in *VSOnline*, I found that the folder *'w15_2'* would change, an indication that this path (and subsequent access failure) is in *VSOnline*.  I have confirmed the user I am using for migration is a project collection admin, project admin, and project collection service account (per the OpsHub help page).

I'm not really sure where to go from here... any ideas how to get around this access denied error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the utility does not have ability to write at location at :\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\TFS_Temp which is used by the utility for temp work space. (It is aliased to O drive). Please check to make sure that this location is writeable.

Comment: Thanks, this certainly helps me understand the issue. I tried running the migration tool as admin, and granted all users full control of \TFS_Temp, but nothing seems to help.  I moved the migration tool to a VM in Azure and am able to run the migration without any issues.  I'm chalking this one up to the very tight security we have on our local computers at work.